# indy Tcp Connection

Tags: delphi, indy

iam trying to test my application to public network so i will use my own ip as server , i already did port forward  in my router settings, " my goal is reach this application to computers out side my network " but i only can receive data  i cannot send from my main ip to other computer ,, i have disabled my firewall also the other pc firewall is this problem of my router ? or my network ? 
i tried to disable router firewall but still same problem is there other things i have to check ?  also i set my indtCP server binding to 0.0.0.0 to reach all network.

Comment: *"I can only receive data, I cannot send from my server to clients"*, that's just how client/server architecture behaves (if that's the problem you're trying to resolve). Clients connect to your server and when they are connected, you can send them data.

Comment: Thank You for making me understand something .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to send, but only **after** the client connects to your server.

When a client connects you should handle `OnConnect` event of your `TIdTCPServer` component. `AThread` parameter represent your client. You can respond to it by, for example:

```
AThread.Connection.Write ('Hi!');
```

You can disconnect the client by:

```
AThread.Connection.Disconnect;
```

Of course, many clients can be connected at the same time. In this case, you should keep track on all (dis)connected clients.

Comment: Note that this is Indy 9 code. In Indy 10, instead of AThread.Connection use AContext.IOHandler